# Superset - SQL Server Analysis Services Compatibility

Tags: sql-server, ssas, apache-superset

I am just starting to look at Apache Superset and wondered if anyone knows or has been able to hook SQL Server Analysis Services up as a datasource? I want to pull data into Superset from the cubes using MDX.

I am not sure if this is possible yet so will raise it as a new feature on GitHub, unless of course someone has done it before?

Answer (score 0):

I think Superset can only be connected to databases that support SQL Interface as per the documentation, so I suppose this is not possible at the moment.